# pxssh how to sendline 'N' to prompt "[Y/N]"

Tags: python, pexpect, pxssh

I want to use pxssh to make a auto-upgrade script for NetScaler---a FreeBSD based product.

I successfully upload and tar firmware on FreeBSD and install it.

With promop "Do you want to enable it NOW? [Y/N]" , my script failed to sendline "No" to it

Error Code is "'str' object is not callable"

Below is output:

```
You can also configure this feature anytime using the command line 
interface or the configuration utility.  Please see the documentation 
for further details.

Do you want to enable it NOW? [Y/N]
'str' object is not callable
[root@raynor NS_Auto_Upgrade]#
```

Below is my script

```
try:

    ssh_command = pxssh.pxssh()
    hostname = remotename
    username = loginname
    password = loginpassword
    #ssh_command.PROMPT= '> | Do you want to enable it NOW? [Y/N]'           #self-defined original prompt 
    ssh_command.PROMPT= '> '           #self-defined original prompt 
    #ssh_command.login(hostname, username, password,original_prompt='[#$>]')
    ssh_command.login(hostname, username, password,auto_prompt_reset=False)
    ssh_command.prompt()
    print(ssh_command.before)
    ssh_command.sendline('shell')   # run a command
    #print(ssh_command.before)
    #ssh_command.PROMPT='Do you want to enable it NOW? [Y/N]'             # match the prompt
    print(f[0:-4])
    ssh_command.prompt()
    print(ssh_command.before)
    ssh_command.sendline('mkdir /var/nsinstall/%s && ls -l /var/nsinstall' % f[0:-4])
    ssh_command.prompt()
    ssh_command.sendline('tar xzvf /var/nsinstall/%s -C /var/nsinstall/%s' % (f, f[0:-4]))
    ssh_command.prompt()
    print(ssh_command.before)
    ssh_command.sendline('/var/nsinstall/%s/installns' % f[0:-4])
    ssh_command.PROMPT='Do you want to enable it NOW? [Y/N]'
    ssh_command.prompt()
    print(ssh_command.before)
    ssh_command.sendline('No')
    ssh_command.PROMPT('Reboot NOW? [Y/N]')
    ssh_command.prompt()
    ssh_command.sendline('Yes')
    #ssh_command.prompt()
    print(ssh_command.before)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your library at all, but I'd guess the issue is the conflict between these two lines:

```
ssh_command.PROMPT='Do you want to enable it NOW? [Y/N]'
...
ssh_command.PROMPT('Reboot NOW? [Y/N]')
```

I'm not sure which is correct, but probably you want to either be calling `PROMPT` both time, or assigning to it both times, not assigning once and calling the other.

Comment: Thanks for your response!
The first prompt is "do you want to enable…",and I need to send line "No" ,then process moves on and 2nd prompt "reboot now " , at that time , I need to input "Yes"

Hope it can help you understand

Comment: Yes, but in one place you're doing `PROMPT=...` and in the other place you're doing `PROMPT(...)`. The second one is probably supposed to be like the first one (though I suppose it could be the reverse, I don't know your library at all). Note that for debugging, it may be useful to remove the `try`/`except` blocks you're using to catch the exception. Letting it crash the program may be helpful since it will show you a traceback of the exception identifying exactly where it occurred.

Comment: You mean that if I defined PROMPT before, that will last to the end of function.

Thanks for your advice, I will try to remove try/except block. What I am confused is can pxssh expect such kind of prompt "Reboot now[Y/N]"

Comment: I don't see why not. I've looked briefly at the docs and I think that if you want to search for a special kind of prompt for a few lines, you probably shouldn't be using the `prompt()` method for those but instead the more basic `expect` method (documented [here](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.expect)). The `prompt` method is for when you plan to repeatedly match the same thing (as you're doing in the earlier lines of your code).

Comment: Yeah! Sure, I passed the test by using `expect_exact()` function,This is key point that `prompt()` can only match "$#>" maybe.Thanks very much for your advice!!!